# Connecting 3 OpenVPN connections through a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, openvpn

For work I need to connect to 3 different OpenVPN connections every day. I'm using a shell script to speed this up, but I feel like it could be done better.

Currently my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/vpns
sudo openssl aes-128-cbc -d < login.conf.aes > login.conf

cd ~/vpns/live_vpn
(sudo openvpn --config config.ovpn --auth-user-pass ~/vpns/login.conf) &
cd ~/vpns/mgmt_vpn
(sudo openvpn --config config.ovpn --auth-user-pass ~/vpns/login.conf) &
cd ~/vpns/test_vpn
(sudo openvpn --config config.ovpn --auth-user-pass ~/vpns/login.conf) &

cd ~/vpns
sleep 20
wipe -f login.conf
```

Openssl decrypts a file containing the username and password for the connections, which is then wiped after the connections are established.

This works but has some problems:

- The repeated `cd`s seem inelegant.
- I hope the `sleep` command (which gives openvpn time to use the decrypted login file) can be replaced so that the wipe occurs as soon as the connections are established.
- I've called `sudo` above the openvpn lines as otherwise they seem to 'pile up' on the shell and give no opportunity to enter the password.

**My question is: What would be a better way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about whether or not storing the username/password combination in a variable will work - it definitely won't if your sudo configuration requires a password, but at the least you can implement a loop similar to what's below.  If storing the username/password in the variable does work, you won't need to write a file with your credentials at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
VPNDIR=${HOME}/vpns
CONFIG=${VPNDIR}/login.conf
OCWD=${PWD}

cd ${VPNDIR}
OLDIFS=${IFS} ; IFS=''
CREDS="$(openssl aes-128-cbc -d < login.conf.aes)"
IFS=${OLDIFS}

for Z in live_vpn mgmt_vpn test_vpn; do
   cd ${VPNDIR}/${Z}
   (printf "${CREDS}\n" | sudo openvpn --config config.ovpn --auth-user-pass) &
done

unset CREDS
cd ${OCWD}
```